# Is it OK to create a tag about exercises from one particular book?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is it OK to create a tag about exercises from one particular book?

The book I have in mind is a book with many hard exercises and unproved theorems in it (the total is about 200 or 300 maybe more), but it's a realy good book otherwise IMO. I won't try to create such a tag till I get favorable approval here, and as I haven't seen any tag of this type before I thought it would be worthy matter to ask here. Nevertheless, I believe that instead putting the title of the book many times in the head of the post, it would be better to have a tag for it.

Comment: Better to rely only on tags according to topic/field of mathematics, and not source or author, since many mathematicians cover, or write excellent texts, in a number of fields/subfields.

Comment: See [Adding (hartshorne) tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10056/adding-hartshorne-tag) and its linked Questions.  The consensus (with which I agree) seems to be that these are not good candidates for tags.  Mention of a book in the body of the Question (or perhaps also in the title) should suffice to make the exercises discoverable by those with such an interest.

Comment: That's ok I get it no named-tag or book-tag that's the way people look at MSE, it's a bit harsh but ok. Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tag for a book or an author would necessarily be a "meta tag": a tag that describes in which context the question was asked or what the direction of its answer should be.

Meta tags are discouraged, see [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2498/43351).

The primary reason behind this is that they do not help anyone to understand or assess the question any better, which is the main purpose of tags. You could argue that e.g. [hartshorne](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hartshorne) conveys some information. But then, does this weigh up against simply using [algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-geometry) instead?

Including the reference to book or author in your *question* is a different matter altogether: this is very useful for anyone coming upon your question: for answering it, for understanding notation and terminology, as a starting point for further learning, etc. As such it is a valuable piece of context, which is strongly encouraged in the [guideline for posting good questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).